# How do ActiveRecord dynamic attribute-based finders work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've been trying to find the source code so I can understand how [ActiveRecord dynamic attribute-based finders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Dynamic+attribute-based+finders) work. I haven't been able to find where in the source code the definitions live.

Could someone put me to the location in the file(s) that define this functionality? Thanks!

Using Rails 3.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in ActiveRecord::Model and noticed that there was a module included called DynamicMatchers. It looks like this is where all the dynamic attribute finders come from. Essentially it's using method missing and reflecting back on the associated model:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb

Comment: wow, awesome, I think I actually glanced at that file and kept moving. I never would have thought of overriding method_missing. Thanks!